# Insert into table from muliple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert, row-number

I'm trying to make a insert from multiple tables but I'm having some issues. When I tried testdata with a sample size of 10 entries, it works fine. When I try to run it on my actual task i get an constraint error. There are around 13000 entries that should be inserted.

What I'm trying to do is to move Data from 4 different tables to a 5th table that allready exists. Table 5 has a primary key that will not increment by itself so I need to define it in the insert query and increment it.

Here is my insert so far:

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION
    (INCREMENT,ID, EID, TEXT, DID, LOCATION, CODE, TEXT, QUANTITY)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)),
    p.ID,
    f.EID,
    p.TEXT,
    d.ID,
    f.LOCATION,
    d.CODE,
    s.TEXT,
    f.QUANTITY
FROM PROD p
left join Fil  f on f.EID= p.EID
left join DEEP d on f.LOCATION= d.LOCATION
left join SIZE s on d.ID = s.ID
```

I am not familiar with the function ROW_NUMBER so I assume my mistake is there.

Comment: Does the SELECT part work stand-alone?

Comment: Check your query you trying to insert 8 column but passing 9 values

Comment: Indeed, there's a missing column for the `ROW_NUMBER()` attribute OR the `p.ID` if `Location.ID` was supposed to be populated with the row numbers.

Comment: Please show: (1) the defintion of table `LOCATION`, (2) any compile or runtime errors that you see.

Comment: My SELECT part works stand-alone. Sorry about the missmatch with values. I updated my question so now im trying to insert 9 coloums by passing 9 values

Comment: " i get an constraint error", which is?

Comment: The definition of the field INCREMENT: [INCREMENT] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ1_INCREMENT] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `INCREMENT` column is `UNIQUE` and you probably are trying to add values that already exist. You can use the following to ensure they don't repeat:

```
DECLARE @MaxIncrement INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(INCREMENT), 0) FROM Location)

INSERT INTO LOCATION
    (INCREMENT,ID, EID, TEXT, DID, LOCATION, CODE, TEXT, QUANTITY)
SELECT
    @MaxIncrement + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)),
    p.ID,
    f.EID,
    p.TEXT,
    d.ID,
    f.LOCATION,
    d.CODE,
    s.TEXT,
    f.QUANTITY
FROM PROD p
left join Fil  f on f.EID= p.EID
left join DEEP d on f.LOCATION= d.LOCATION
left join SIZE s on d.ID = s.ID
```

I would also suggest using an `IDENTITY` on that column (you will have to re-create the table, moving the data away as a middle step), so you don't have this problem any more.

Comment: Thank you. Ill try this. May i ask why i get unique values with the Row_Number? I thought  for every insert it will just count the value up in the INCREMENT coloumn. How can i end up with values that allready exist then?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is a function that returns a row number from your `SELECT`, it is not related at any point to the table you are inserting the rows into. These numbers always start at 1 and goes onward (it might reset with a `PARTITION BY` clause). What you want is to declare your table column as `IDENTITY`, which is an auto-numbered integer that gets automatically set whenever you insert a row. You can search another questions in StackOverflow about how to change an existing column to `IDENTITY` (it's not so straightforward).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I think ill read a bit more up on ROW_NUMBER. Sadly i can't change this table due to several reasons.